# how to limit the quantity volume in android, ios applications

Tags: android, ios, react-native

i am interested in developing the middleman platform between the seller and buyer ,how can we control the sellers quantity(volume) level,is their any api for limiting the quantity level for reactnative

code for my question or any source for coding, any kind of leads are appreciable.

Comment: You need to have a web server that has all the data. The apps communicate with it and load all the required information from the server. Either develop something on your own or use a platform as a service like Firebase.